# How to access uploaded file from multer?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, multer, multer-s3

Im able to upload an image to `S3`. Now, if the file selected is `.gif`, I want to be able to convert the `.gif` file to `.mp4` and upload the converted file to `S3`. I am able to convert a `.gif` to `.mp4` with `ffmpeg` only if I give the path of the file. How do I access the uploaded file from `Multer`? Below is my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var multer = require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');


var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'myBucket',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            var extension = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();

                if(extension=="gif"){
                console.log("Uploaded a .gif file");

                ffmpeg(file) //THIS IS NOT WORKING
                    .setFfmpegPath("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")
                      .output('./outputs/2.mp4')    //TRYING TO UPLOAD LOCALLY, WHICH FAILS
                      .on('end', function() {
                        console.log('Finished processing');
                      })
                      .run();
            }

            cb(null, filename);
        }
    })
});
```

I'm trying to access the uploaded file like this:  `ffmpeg(file)` since `file` is an argument passed in the `multer` function.

My form :

```
<form action="/upload" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

In which part of the process do I convert the file?

Please help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to process a file locally that's on `s3`. The file needs to be your server's file system or at the very least be publicly available on `s3`. So you have two options here.

**a)** You could first upload all the files to the server where express is running (**not** on `s3`, first we store them temporarily). If the file is a `.gif`, process it and upload the resulting `.mp4` file, otherwise upload to `s3`. Here's a working example:

```
var fs         = require('fs')
var path       = require('path')
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var aws        = require('aws-sdk');
var multer     = require('multer');
var ffmpeg     = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var shortid    = require('shortid');


aws.config.update(/* your config */);


var app    = express();
var s3     = new aws.S3();
var bucket = 'myBucket';

var upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: './uploads/',
        filename: function (req, file, cb){
            // user shortid.generate() alone if no extension is needed
            cb( null, shortid.generate() + path.parse(file.originalname).ext);
        }
    })
});


//----------------------------------------------------
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {

    var fileInfo = path.parse(req.file.filename);

    if(fileInfo.ext === '.gif'){

        var videoPath = 'uploads/' + fileInfo.name + '.mp4';

        ffmpeg(req.file.path)
            .setFfmpegPath("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")
            .output(videoPath)
            .on('end', function() {
                console.log('[ffmpeg] processing done');
                uploadFile(videoPath, fileInfo.name + '.mp4');
            })
            .run();
    }
    else {
        uploadFile(req.file.path, req.file.filename);
    }

    res.end();
});


//----------------------------------------------------
function uploadFile(source, target){

    fs.readFile(source, function (err, data) {

        if (!err) {

            var params = {
                Bucket      : bucket,
                Key         : target,
                Body        : data
            };

            s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('[s3] file uploaded:');
                    console.log(data);
                    fs.unlink(source); // optionally delete the file
                }
                else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


app.listen(3000);
```

**b)** Alternatively if you're ok with making your `s3` files public you could upload them all using `multer-s3`. Since `ffmpeg` also accepts network locations as input paths you can pass it the `s3` location of your `.gif` files and then upload the converted `.mp4` files:

```
var fs         = require('fs')
var path       = require('path')
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var aws        = require('aws-sdk');
var multer     = require('multer');
var ffmpeg     = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var multerS3   = require('multer-s3');


aws.config.update(/* your config */);


var app    = express();
var s3     = new aws.S3();
var bucket = 'myBucket';

var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: bucket,
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        },
        acl: 'public-read'
    })
});

----------------------------------------------------
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {

    var fileInfo = path.parse(req.file.originalname);

    if(fileInfo.ext === '.gif'){

        var videoPath = 'uploads/' + fileInfo.name + '.mp4';

        ffmpeg(req.file.location)
            .setFfmpegPath("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")
            .output(videoPath)
            .on('end', function() {
                console.log('[ffmpeg] processing done');
                uploadFile(videoPath, fileInfo.name + '.mp4');
            })
            .run();
    }

    res.end();
})


//----------------------------------------------------
function uploadFile(source, target){

    fs.readFile(source, 'base64', function (err, data) {

        if (!err) {

            var params = {
                Bucket      : bucket,
                Key         : target,
                Body        : data,
                ContentType : 'video/mp4'
            };

            s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('[s3] file uploaded:');
                    console.log(data);
                    fs.unlink(source); // optionally delete the file
                }
                else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

app.listen(3000);
```

For both examples, remember to create an `uploads/` folder and use your `aws` configuration.

Comment: Sorry was travelling. Tried the first example. The files uploaded to S3 are getting the `.mp4` extension regardless if they are `.gif` or not. The uploaded `.mp4` is not able to play, it says unknown file format. And this is for the `.gif` uploaded which saves in S3 as `.mp4`.

Comment: But the `.mp4` files that are in the `/uploads` folder are converted to `.mp4` and are playable. I commented the unlink part to check this. So it seems that the converted file is not getting uploaded to S3 and any file going to S3 is getting the  `.mp4` extension. I like the first approach. Please help in making it work.

Comment: While you're at it mate, could you please tell me where do I rename the file? I am using `shortid` an npm package to generate URL friendly links. I'm guessing it to be in the `params` but not sure. Thanks a mil.

Comment: Edited option a), files keep their ending now. Also removed the `base64` encoding when reading, files on s3 are ok now. Using `shortid` instead of the original name.

Comment: Uploading `.gif` is getting converted to `.mp4` and uploading fine to `S3`. Uploading `.jpg` is getting uploaded as .jpg but when I download it or try to open, its opening as `.mp4` also downloading as `.mp4`. Not able to figure out why. I believe because of `ContentType : 'video/mp4'`

Comment: I tried `ContentType : 'jpg, jpeg, video/mp4'` but non gifs are getting saved as `.mp4`

Comment: Downloaded the file that was saved as jog but was playing as mp4, renamed it to jog, and its opening fine. what could be the issue?

Comment: Was setting `ContentType : 'video/mp4'` for all uploads, removed that part. Should be ok now.

Comment: You son of a gun you .. thanks a million !!! Really thank you .. Been trying this since more than 2 weeks. Thank you. God bless you!

Comment: One last thing, how do i access the name of the file from `app.post('/upload')`? In case I want to put the name in DB. I am talking about the new name generated by `shortid`. Thanks again.

Comment: Exactly. Awesome, glad to help!

Comment: Please see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541138/transform-upload-with-nodejs-multer/46026368#46026368) for another implementation of downloading the file from AWS S3 and resizing using sharp.

Comment: Please see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541138/transform-upload-with-nodejs-multer/46026368#comment79013788_46026368) to your implementation.